# java depísito en cuentas bancarias

Tags: java

necesito si me pueden ayudar a encontrar el error a este programa, que consta de cuenta bancarias, el problema es que me arroja error al realizar y girar un deposito de una cuenta creada.

Se agradece

```
package control_7;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Control_7 {

    int contar=0, nro=201801;
    CuentaBancaria cuenta [] = new CuentaBancaria[5];

    public Control_7(){

        String ax;
        int op=0;

        do{
            ax = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "1. CREAR UNA CUENTA BANCARIA \n"
                                                  +"2. VER LA LISTA DE CLIENTES \n"
                                                  +"3. EFECTUAR UN DEPOSITO \n"
                                                  +"4. EFECTUAR UN GIRO \n"
                                                  +"5. SALIR");
            if(ax!=null && !ax.equals("")){
                op = Integer.parseInt(ax);

                switch(op){
                    case 1:
                        ingresar();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mostrar();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        deposito();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        girar();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        break;
                    default:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INGRESE UNA OPCION CORRECTA!!!");                  
                }
            }

        }while(op!=5);
    }

    public void ingresar(){        


        String nombre, apellido, direccion;
        Double saldo;        

        nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INGRESAR NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE: ");
        apellido = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INGRESAR EL APELLIDO: ");
        direccion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INGRESE LA DIRECCION DEL CLIENTE: ");
        saldo = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INGRESE DEPOSITO INICIAL: "));

        CuentaBancaria temp = new CuentaBancaria();

        temp.setNro(nro); 
        temp.setNombre(nombre); 
        temp.setApellido(apellido);
        temp.setDireccion(direccion);
        temp.setSaldo(saldo);        

        cuenta[contar] = temp;
        contar++;  
        nro++;      
    }

    private void mostrar(){

        String ay="";

        for(int i=0; i<contar; i++){
            ay+="NUMERO DE CUENTA:    "+cuenta[i].getNro()+"\n"
              + "NOMBRE:              "+cuenta[i].getNombre()+"\n"
              + "APELLIDO:            "+cuenta[i].getApellido()+"\n"
              + "DIRECCION:           "+cuenta[i].getDireccion()+"\n"
              + "SALDO DE LA CUENTA:  "+cuenta[i].getSaldo()+"\n\n";        
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ay);
    }

    private void deposito(){

        String ax;
        Double dep = null;
        int c;

        ax = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INGRESE EL NUMERO DE CUENTA A LA CUAL DESEA EFECTUAR EL DEPOSITO");

        if(ax!=null && !ax.equals("")){
            c = Integer.parseInt(ax); ax="";
            if(contar!=0){
                for(int i=0; i<contar; i++){
                    if(cuenta[i].getNro() == c){
                        ax="";
                        dep =Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INGRESE EL MONTO DEL DEPOSITO"));
                        if (dep>0){
                        dep+=cuenta[i].getSaldo();
                        ax+="Número de Cuenta:   "+cuenta[i].getNro()+"\n"
                          + "Nombre:             "+cuenta[i].getNombre()+"\n"
                          + "Apellido:           "+cuenta[i].getApellido()+"\n"
                          + "Direccion:          "+cuenta[i].getDireccion()+"\n"
                          + "Saldo:              "+cuenta[i].getSaldo()+"\n";

                          break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        ax="  LA CUENTA NO ESTA ASIGNADA \n"
                          +"       INTENTE NUEVAMENTE... \n"; 
                    }
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ax);
            }

        }
    }


    private String girar(){

        String an;
        Double ret=null;
        int c;

        an = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INGRESE EL NUMERO DE CUENTA A LA CUAL DESEA EFECTUAR EL GIRO");

        if(an!=null && !an.equals("")){
            c = Integer.parseInt(an); an="";
            if(contar!=0){
                for(int i=0; i<contar; i++){
                    if(cuenta[i].getNro() == c){
                        an="";
                        ret =Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INGRESE EL MONTO DE RETIRO"));
                        if(ret>cuenta[i].getSaldo()){
                            return "SALDO INSUFICIENTE\n"
                                 + "INGRESE NUEVO MONTO\n";
                        }else{
                        ret-=cuenta[i].getSaldo();
                        an+="Número de Cuenta:   "+cuenta[i].getNro()+"\n"
                          + "Nombre:             "+cuenta[i].getNombre()+"\n"
                          + "Apellido:           "+cuenta[i].getApellido()+"\n"
                          + "Direccion:          "+cuenta[i].getDireccion()+"\n"
                          + "Saldo:              "+cuenta[i].getSaldo()+"\n";
                          break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        an="  LA CUENTA NO ESTA ASIGNADA \n"
                          +"       INTENTE NUEVAMENTE... \n"; 
                    }
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, an);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Control_7 y = new Control_7();
        System.exit(0);        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que veo es que en tú método de Depositar() no estás cambiando el valor del nuevo saldo, éstas sumando pero no lo estás cambiando.

```
dep =Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INGRESE EL MONTO DEL DEPOSITO"));
                        if (dep>0){
                        dep+=cuenta[i].getSaldo();  //Solo se suma pero no se cambia
```

Para poder cambiar el saldo necesitarás usar el set de tu variable, de tal modo que te quedaría así:

```
dep =Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INGRESE EL MONTO DEL DEPOSITO"));
                        if (dep>0){
                        dep+=cuenta[i].getSaldo();  //Solo se suma pero no se cambia
                        cuenta[i].setSaldo(dep);    //Se actualiza el nuevo saldo
```

Y en el método de girar() tu error radica en el mal uso del **operador de asignación** -=.

En tu código lo estás colocando así

```
ret-=cuenta[i].getSaldo();
```

Si revisamos la función de ese operador en un ejemplo:

A-=B es el equivalente a decir   A = A-B.

Entonces aplicado a tu solución, el equivalente sería

```
ret = ret - cuenta[i].getSaldo()
```

lo que provoca que el resultado te lo lance como negativo.

Para resolver eso basta que reestructurar la forma en que ese está restando y luego como en el método de depositar, actualizar.

```
            double total = cuenta[i].getSaldo()-ret;   //Resta el monto del saldo actual                                        
            cuenta[i].setSaldo(total);  //Actualiza el total de la cuenta
```

Con esto arreglarías los problemas de suma y resta del saldo inicial. Saludos.

Comment: angel muchas gracias por tu ayuda, te pasaste

Comment: No quiero ser inoportuno, pero me ayudarías mucho a mí y a la comunidad en marcar mi respuesta como la correcta con cheque. Un gusto ayudarte. Saludos